# Box Shadows in CSS

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, css

This is not a question, but just a rant. Or maybe a question... or maybe I just don't know much about box shadows..

In order to use box shadows in CSS3 in different browsers, here what I have to do:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #676767;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #676767;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #676767;
```

Is there anyone else finding this incredibly stupid in order for Firefox, Opera and Safari/Chrome/Webkit to work? And it will not even work in IE at all!

Is there anything I can do to reduce the duplicated CSS values?

Thanks, 
badallen

Comment: I agree in that it *is* incredibly complicated to use, but it's still better than not having any box shadows at all. Good discussion on the issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218795/seeking-opinions-on-vendor-specific-prefixes)

Comment: There was great hope that they would stop doing this (&$%#*!@ but alas, it was not meant to be.

Comment: @Pekka — ooh yes, I think Bobince nailed it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218795/seeking-opinions-on-vendor-specific-prefixes/3218870#3218870

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `box-shadow` is not yet officially specified, you need the vendor-specific prefixes (eg: `-moz`, `-webkit`, `-ms`). IE doesn't support them period; I'd recommend using [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/) if you want to use IE. PIE also adds support for other CSS 3 eye-candy like `border-radius` and gradients.

If you want to avoid having to write the same code every time, I'd recommend using LESS or SASS and their mixins:

http://lesscss.org/
http://sass-lang.com/

Answer (score 1):

Note that [as of 2010-09-14](http://blog.mozilla.com/meeting-notes/archives/380), the -moz prefix has been removed for Mozilla Platform builds.  Firefox 4 will fully support box-shadow!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately but inevitably, this is the way standards are made:

1. Part of the standard is specified. (Often just by one browser-maker internally.)
2. One or more companies implement that part in a browser.
3. The standard is revised based on real-world usage of the standard as implemented so far.

The key part is 3 — if the vendor prefixes weren’t used, part 3 couldn’t happen, so mistakes couldn’t be rectified without a lot of pain for every web developer in the world. (See e.g. the Internet Explorer box model, the rats nest of bugs that is Internet Explorer 6’s float implementation, and, well, pretty much the entire history of Internet Explorer up until version 8.)

At some point, browsers that require vendor prefixes for `box-shadow` will be unpopular enough that you can skip `-webkit-box-shadow` and `-moz-box-shadow`. Until then, it’s just the price you pay for using bleeding edge CSS features.

Comment: There's an interesting article by Eric Meyer on A List Apart, regarding implementation of CSS, vendor-prefixing and such: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prefix-or-posthack/

Comment: @David: ooh yes, that’s a great one. I suspect my answer pretty much just badly summarised my memory of that article.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a box with following css

```
box-shadow: 0 3px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
```